# jquery running when new images load

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

So I have a site that has 2 containers `#container` and `#container2`. I use jquery to `append` content that is of a certain size to one container, and the others to the other. Here is that code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.entry').each(function() {
        if ($(this).height() > 200) {
            $('#container2').append(this);
        }
        else {
            $('#container').append(this);
        }
    });
});
```

So my issue is that with the infinite scroll and masonry, when the new content becomes available, the jquery does not run again in order to append the content to the right container. What can I add so that it will be able to append the content to the correct container?

Note: Each container can have tens of thousands of images.

Update:

Here is my masonry code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var $wall = $('#container');
    $wall.imagesLoaded(function() {
        $wall.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.entry, .entry_photo',
            isAnimated: false
        });
    });

    $wall.infinitescroll({
        navSelector: '#page-nav',
        nextSelector: '#page-nav a',
        itemSelector: '.entry, .entry_photo',
        bufferPx: 2000,
        debug: false,
        errorCallback: function() {
            $('#infscr-loading').fadeOut('normal');
        }},
    function(newElements) {
        var $newElems = $(newElements);
        $newElems.hide();
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function() {
            $wall.masonry('appended', $newElems, {isAnimated: false}, function() {
                $newElems.fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });
    });
    $('#container').show(500);
});
```

So what happens is that the next posts when they load, all load into `#container` regardless of their height. This clearly shows that masonry is working fine, but it's just not calling the jquery again when they load. **Is there any way to insure that it calls the jquery I need? How do I do that?**

Comment: So you are using the masonry plugin and you want to "reorder" new content?

Comment: I am familiar with masonry and I am using it's infinite scroll abilities. But the issue is that the jquery does not run when the next posts load...is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to initialize `masonry plugin` after adding your `content` in `containers`

like,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.entry').each(function(){
        if($(this).height()>200){
            $('#container2').append(this);
        }
        else{
            $('#container').append(this);
        }
    });
    // masonry plugin initialization after adding content to div
});
```